How to prove the signless Laplacian polynomial is reconstructible?
On page 253 in the book "An Introduction to the Theory of Graph Spetra" by Cvetkovic, Rowlinson and Simic, the authors write "We mention in passing that the $Q$-polynomial of a graph is reconstructible from the deck of vertex-deleted subgraphs (see [Ded]), a result analogous to Tutte's result for adjacency spectrum".
[Ded] Dedo E., La reconstruibilita del polinomio carrateristico del comutato di un grafo, Boll. Unione Mat. Ital. 18A (1981), 423–429.
I would like to see a proof of Dedo's result that is written in English, as I do not understand the language used in [Ded]. (The reference [Ded] is not available.)
Is there any other reference that contains the proof for the reconstructibilty of the $Q$-polynomial (signless Laplacian polynomial) of a graph?
